# how to export header and data from separate tables while creating SSIS package

Tags: business-intelligence, dts, ssis

I have two tables in my database i.e. Columns and Data. Data in these tables are like:

Columns:

```
    ID

    Name
```

Data:

> 1      John
>
> 2      Steve

Now I want to create a package which will create a csv file like:

```
ID  NAME
------------
1   John
2   Steve
```

Can we achieve the same output? I have searched on google but I haven't found any solution.

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect through a script task OR you can create a temporary dataset in SQL Server where you combine the first row of your Column table and append data from the Data table to this. My guess is, you would have to fight with the metadata issues while doing anything of this sort. Another suggestion that I can think of is to dump the combination to a flat file, but again you will have to take care of the metadata conversion.